# Looking for a BitBucket Workflow

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have been using Beanstalk and TortoiseSVN for some time now and I am looking to change to Bitbucket with SourceTree. While working in groups we have the truck, which is master now in bitbucket am i right? Then our users switch to trunk to then create new branches for themselves. After a time all branches are merged back to the trunk. How do I use SourceTree to create branches for users and then merge them back.
Maybe there is a better way to use it altogether, could you advise please.

Comment: SoruceTree has built-in support for Git Flow.

Answer (score 2):

Atlassian nicely documented possible [workflows with Git](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows), you should start from there. If you are familiar with TortoiseSVN try TortoiseGit.

Comment: Does it work ok with Bitbucket? Thought it only worked with GitHub

Comment: GitHub, Bitbucket, Beanstalk and so on are web-based hosting services for projects that use Git revision control systems. It depends from your preferences where do you want to host the code.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this article, it's a well known git workflow which is also implemented directly in SourceTree ("Git Flow"-Button on top right):

[git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

And here is a blog entry from SourceTree Blog on how to use it in SourceTree:

[sourcetree blog](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/01/smart-branching-with-sourcetree-and-git-flow/)